# How can I copy data from an excel file into Azure DataStudio to create a table with it? (on a mac) thanks

Tags: excel, create-table, azure-data-studio

I have a table I made in excel and I want to have the same table in my Azure DataStudio, how can I copy the data over? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the extension `SQL Server Import`. Also, you should have a database server and a database that are ready to use. The extension provides an import wizard that you can open by clicking `Ctrl + I`.

N.B: The wizard will create a new table, it is not possible to insert the data in an existing table

You will find more details in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15.

[image]

Comment: I tried. However this extension is totally not working. I already installed SQL Server Import, them clicking Ctrl + I. Nothing happened. No error or any message were shown....

Comment: The version of this extension only seems to support text files, not Excel.  The Import-Export Wizard you refer to is available to me in SQL Server Management Studio, but not Azure Data Studio.  @Mohamed Sahbi, are you able to import Excel files using the Azure Data Studio extension ```SQL Server Import```?